# Shortcut for conditional variable manipulation in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

One of the parameters my API controller receives has a big key name and I need to convert it from string to integer, if it is present, before sending it to the model to be persisted. Usually I would do one of the following:

```
params[:really_big_key_name] = params[:really_big_key_name].to_i unless params[:really_big_key_name].blank?
```

or

```
params[:really_big_key_name] = params[:really_big_key_name].present? ? params[:really_big_key_name].to_i : nil
```

As you can see, the code line becomes big, with more than 80 characters, and I want to stick with Ruby best practices. Is there a shorter, more Ruby way to do the same? Maybe "in place" methods. Something like arrays do with bang methods. Unfortunately, `to_i!` does not exist for strings, which is exactly what I need.

Comment: I'd say an in place method could not exist because that would change the type from `string` to `number`. You could always use [try](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
params[:really_big_key_name] = params[:really_big_key_name].try(:to_i)
```

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'try' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @BradWerth are you using Rails or pure Ruby? `try` is part of Rails since 2.3.2.

Comment: You're right - I was not using Rails. FWIW, a pure-ruby version of this answer is `params[:really_big_key_name] = params[:really_big_key_name]&.to_i`

Comment: @BradWerth ah, good call. Obviously, in this case the OP is using Rails but still very good to know. :thumbsup:

Comment: I will stick with `try`. @BradWerth's suggestion using `params[:really_big_key_name]&.to_i` is very nice, but it requires Ruby 2.3 and currently I am using Ruby 2.1. Thanks for your answers, guys!

Comment: @Havox The only thing that sucks about these answers is that they slightly differ from your original example. In your example, the variable is never reassigned to the same value, in both provided answers, the variable is always reassigned. Probably not a huge deal, but maybe worth noting.